# How to create a chart or table from Custom DataSource

Tags: java, jasper-reports, datasource

I'm creating a report using JasperReports, I already have data passing to the report from the datasource however im not sure on how to get it to work with charts or tables, I'm sure its the getdata function i should be calling for the Use JrDatasource expression but I'm not sure how to call it or what to include. Could someone help?

I've tried using parameters but there are just no examples of it with a custom Datasource, only other datasource I've seen is JRBean and that's different from what I've implemented.

```
    private static final String[] nameArray = {"Frank", "Joseph", "Marco", "Carl", "Lenny", "Homer", "Teodor", "Leopold"};

    private static final Integer[] ageArray = {50,30,40,46,44,26,32,21};

    private int counter = -1;

    private HashMap<String, Integer> fieldsNumber = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    private int lastFieldsAdded = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean next() throws JRException {
        if (counter<nameArray.length-1) {
            counter++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFieldValue(JRField jrField) throws JRException {
        Integer fieldIndex;
        if (fieldsNumber.containsKey(jrField.getName()))
            fieldIndex = fieldsNumber.get(jrField.getName());
        else {
            fieldsNumber.put(jrField.getName(), lastFieldsAdded);
            fieldIndex = lastFieldsAdded;
            lastFieldsAdded ++;
        }
        if (fieldIndex == 0) return nameArray[counter];
        else if (fieldIndex == 1) return ageArray[counter];
        return "";
    }

    public Object getFieldValue2(JRField jrField) throws JRException {
        if (jrField.getName().equals("Name")) return nameArray[counter];
        else if (jrField.getName().equals("Age")) return ageArray[counter];
        return "";
    }

    public static JRDataSource getDataSource(){
        return new Implementation();
    }
```

The Jrxml table:

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="LeveyJenDataset" uuid="0b1d0395-fcd9-471a-b840-e800fbc4cad8">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[Implementation()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="3211405d-427f-43db-8d48-babd275bfaa8">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="a59d1ac1-555d-487d-8844-4e75510a2ce0"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Field_1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="995816a4-8066-421b-9a41-650fe35b0a11"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Field_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="174224c5-0ff0-41f2-be74-2a32f32d3d5f">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="59835446-f3e1-442b-a9fb-55243ec97d10"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Field_2]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="fe462425-2890-4c63-83b3-46d02fb0b7dc"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Field_2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="LeveyJenDataset" uuid="0b1d0395-fcd9-471a-b840-e800fbc4cad8">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[Implementation()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="3211405d-427f-43db-8d48-babd275bfaa8">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="a59d1ac1-555d-487d-8844-4e75510a2ce0"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Field_1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="995816a4-8066-421b-9a41-650fe35b0a11"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Field_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="174224c5-0ff0-41f2-be74-2a32f32d3d5f">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="59835446-f3e1-442b-a9fb-55243ec97d10"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Field_2]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="fe462425-2890-4c63-83b3-46d02fb0b7dc"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Field_2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="LeveyJenDataset" uuid="0b1d0395-fcd9-471a-b840-e800fbc4cad8">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[Implementation()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="3211405d-427f-43db-8d48-babd275bfaa8">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="a59d1ac1-555d-487d-8844-4e75510a2ce0"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Field_1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="995816a4-8066-421b-9a41-650fe35b0a11"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Field_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="174224c5-0ff0-41f2-be74-2a32f32d3d5f">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="59835446-f3e1-442b-a9fb-55243ec97d10"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Field_2]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="fe462425-2890-4c63-83b3-46d02fb0b7dc"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Field_2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
```

here i was trying to get field_1 and field_2 to a table however it doesn't output anything for the table and it says method Implementation() is undefined for the report

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, i just added the data adapter to the dataset manually.